# What can be Questions and Answers for Interview on job position on Objects Recognition and Computer Vision?

Tags: computer-vision

What can be Questions  and Answers for Interview on job position for objects recognition and Computer vision?

Please only Qs with links to As.

Please keep being on topic (no general Qs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would let the interviewee describe a computer vision project she worked on: What was the problem? What approaches did she try? What did and whad didn't work? Why didn't it work? How did she measure if something worked or not?

The idea is to find out if the person in question only uses blind trial-and-error to get results, which is usually not a good strategy for complex problems. (Also, it's hard to convincingly fake this kind of knowledge ;-)